# jQuery Scrollify and fixed header

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I have a site with always fixed header and try to use jQuery Scrollify plugin. It works well, but fixed header overlap content. So after every section scrolling part of this section is overlapped. Scrollify have option 'offset', but it not helps. I think it needs to be something like 'negative offset' to make indent from top. For example: -100 etc.

Maybe somebady had issue with this?

Comment: try applying scroll for body content only instead of whole window

Answer (score 1):

To stop overlapping of content, we can do something like this:

```
var $headerHeight = $('.header').height();
$('.header + *').css('top', ($headerHeight));
$('.header + *').css('position', 'relative');
```

We can set top position or top margin to next element of header.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I use 'offset: -100' and it works :)

Ofcource I have page scrolled down for 100px, so this is not full decision, but it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have an inner wrapper within your sections that wraps your content. You could use that to better control the position of your content within the sections to make sure they are clear of the header.